# Issue while updating phpMyAdmin : Composer dependencies

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed LAMP on an AWS EC2 AMI 2 Linux server.
PhpMyAdmin is working fine.
After a few weeks I tried to upgrade phpMyAdmin to the latest version.

I always get the same message after the upgrade :

"Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: xml"

Version installed
PHP : 7.2.34
phpmyadmin : 5.0.4
Mariadb : 10.2.10

I did the upgrade as expected (rename old folder, dwl lastest version, paste config.inc.php).

Any idea ?
Thanks,
El.

Answer (score 0):

no idea why, the upgrade finally worked well after a new try today